# make every alternate or even number column as datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

What do you propose would be the fastest, best way to change every alternate column in pandas to datetime datatype.

Let's say i want to make every even number column as datetime.

Is fetching the column number in a list and then iterating through the list to change datatype a good way ?

```
i=list(range(0,23))
for i in i:
    if i % 2 == 0:
       df.iloc[:,i] = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:,i],errors='coerce')
    else:
       print("Not Applicable")
```

Unfortunately, the above has only managed to change few of the columns to datetime
Is the existing datatype got to do anything with the inconsistent output from this ?

Comment: show an example...

Comment: have edited my question...

Comment: Where's the data showing this problem?

Comment: Do you think `for i in i` is a good idea? I have never seen this before and don't think it's recommended

Answer (score 1):

IIUC need:

```
i= np.arange(0,23,2)
df.iloc[:,i] = df.iloc[:,i].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: And `df.iloc[:, i + 1] = 'Not Applicable'`

Comment: @Alexander - Not sure, OP use it as info - `print("Not Applicable")`

Comment: Yes, maybe. The objective is unclear.  One would also need to make sure that `i + 1` is within bounds for `df`.